# How can I test my routes in Rspec which one resource under another resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have no idea about how to write the test in Rspec about resource under another resource.

My routes code is:

```html
namespace :admin do
  resouce :users do
    resouce :user_restart_passes do
  end
end
```

My test code is

```html
describe "#index" do
  it "should render" do
    get :index
    expext(...).to eq(..)
  end
 end
```

I get the error show:

```html
No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/user_restart_passes"}
```

Comment: you will need to pass user id.

"get :index, user_id: some_user_id"

Also what is the file name/path of your test file?

Comment: I have tried it, the error shows that user_id is unknown key. My file path is /spec/controllers/admins/user_restart_passess_controller_spec.rb